# I can't use python for delphi under python2.6

Tags: python, delphi, python4delphi

My environment is delphi7 and Python2.6.6, python for delphi installed.

But when I run a test app, I got a runtime error.

```
Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Runtime Error!
program:E:\programming\delphi\p4dtest\dd\project1.exe

This application has requeste, the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.  
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

test.py:

```
import ctypes
print 'hello'
```

delphi app main:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
      PyExeFile('test.py', PE);    
end;
```

It runs ok if I remove the line "import ctypes", but failed if ctypes is imported.

I googled and found an issue on this:
http://code.google.com/p/python4delphi/wiki/P4DPython26.

According to the article, I compile the res file and put the res file and Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest even msvcr90.dll in the project folder, add XP_UAC.RES in the project file, but I still got the error.
Then I reinstalled the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package, but it seems not the problem.
Did anyone use the P4D under python2.6 successfully, please tell me how I can make it.

==================================
Now i have solved the ploblem by myself through reading the issues on the official website of P4D:

```
1、In the pythonengine property tab

‍keep set  “UseLastKnownVersion” to True

‍keep ‍set   "DLLName"  to  python26

2、on your PythonEngine component and adjust your define:

{$DEFINE PYTHON26}

which you can do in the project options of Delphi 7.  
Just add PYTHON26 to the "conditional defines" dialog box.
```

By the way, I don't mean to confuse everyone of my question, if it does, I'm sorry for that, so please don't devote others' question arbitrarily if you didn't try by yourself.

Comment: "failed" is not an error report.

Comment: If you want to add clarification, simply edit your question. The answer your posted was simply too large to merge. Answers are reserved for just that, answers to your question.

Comment: sorry to trouble you for this,i'v re-edited the post.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question; you can put your solution in as an answer, then accept that answer in 2 days. Note that many users would appreciate it if you would beef up your editing a bit (Start sentences with a captial letter, use correct interpunction, use a bit more markup, etc). By making your questions and answers readable, you get a much higher chance that people actually read them, try to answer them (if they are questions) and vote for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I did't describe my question clearly.
Now i have solved the ploblem by myself through reading the issues on the official website of P4D:

```
1、In the pythonengine property tab

‍keep set  “UseLastKnownVersion” to True

‍keep ‍set   "DLLName"  to  python26

2、On your PythonEngine component and adjust your define:

{$DEFINE PYTHON26}

which you can do in the project options of Delphi 7.  
Just add PYTHON26 to the "conditional defines" dialog box
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution of ***babykick***, but kept getting the error message:
*can't load python25.dll*

The following worked for me. (delphi7, python26, windows xp sp3)

> Open the TPythonEngine property tab and apply the
>   following modifications
>
> - DllName : python26.dll
> - DllPath : c:\windows\system32\
> - UseLastknownVersion : false